# mongodb connection count not scale balanced between nodes in replicas set

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am now building a web application using MongoDB + Spring Data Mongodb.

This application has an API which is a simple MongoDB query:

```
db.myCollectionName.aggregate([{ "$sample" : { "size" : 100}}, { "$project" : { "myFieldName" : 1, "_id" : 0}}])
```

We randomly pick up 100 documents from `myCollectionName` and project `myFieldName`. It's a simple read request.

Total collection is about 100m records and afak I use `$sample` operator properly:

- `$sample` is the first stage of the pipeline
- `N` is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
- The collection contains more than 100 documents

Our mongodb cluster is a 3 node replicaset, one node handles write requests, and two others handle read requests.

I am testing my application using JMeter, trying to figure how many `TPS` the application can support at most.

**Report shows that, when the number of concurrency is 100, the TPS performance of the application is the best, reaching 1000, with a average 95pct latency of 180ms**. The workload is evenly distributed to the two secondary nodes. The number of operations is about 500, connection count is about 180 in each secondary node.

Meanwhile, on the application side, the work load is fairly low, only 30% of cpu and memory used.

Next, I try to add one more secondary node to see if TPS will increase linearly and now strange things happens:

After the number of concurrency exceeds 100, the TPS of the system does not increase linearly. **The TPS stays in 1000**, with each secondary node handling only 400 operations (same operationCount). As the number of concurrency goes up, average 95pct lantency of the application also begins to degrade, from 180ms to ~450ms.

In the mean time, I notice that **the connectiont count is not evenly established in each secondary node**. One secondary node has established over 300 connections, while two others have only 180. Moreover, as the number of concurrency exceeds 150, slow queries start to appear on the node with more connections.

I can confirm that the work load on the application side is fairly low, with 3 secondary nodes, the application still does not reach its load limitations. The max connection count configured on the MongoDB client side is 2000, as far as I know, it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Review https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst under "Server Selection Algorithm".

First, check the latencies as seen by the driver for each of the servers. Increase the window using `localThresholdMS` URI option if needed.

Then, you either have incorrectly collected the data or you have a server problem, because

> Moreover, as the number of concurrency exceeds 150, slow queries start to appear on nodes with more connections.

If you have a node that is able to sustain 400 connections but with the same workload is not able to sustain >150 <400 connections, that's a server problem that you need to investigate and repair.

After you've done that, note that in the server selection algorithm is this item:

> Of the two randomly chosen servers, select the one with the lower operationCount. If both servers have the same operationCount, select arbitrarily between the two of them.

This is supposed to route queries to less loaded nodes. This naturally doesn't work well if either the nodes are reporting their load incorrectly, or perhaps you are mistaken as to what load you are reading from where.

Comment: Thanks for help. Total 95pct latency is about 180ms, when we come to the best number of concurrency of 90 ~ 100. I retried to augment the number of concurrency from 10 to 160, with 3 secondary nodes, it appears that when the #concurrency exceeds 90 ~ 100, total TPS cannot go up. One secondary bears much more #connections and #activeRead than the other two. However all three nodes handle the same #OPS 400.

Comment: If we degrade the system from 3 secondary to 2 secondary node, MongoDB then works pretty well, with the same best #concurrency of 90 ~ 100, and ~ 1000 tps at most. Each secondary node bears about 600 ops. The problem is, if we then add one more secondary node, it seems to me that the added one only come to share 200 ops from each of the original secondary node, and here comes to 400 ops for each secondary node, total TPS of system remains the same (400 *3 ~= 600 *2 ), however in this setting, one node begins to work strangely, bearing more #connections.

Comment: I double-checked the setting and configuration for each secondary MongoDB process, they are the same. Each server performance is also comparable. @D. SM

Comment: BTW, increase `localThresholdMS` from 15ms to 50ms seems having no effect.